# How to add scrollbar inside container in accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using accordion. Here, Accordion functionality is working. I want to insert vertical, and Horizontal scrollbar in body content. How to add scroll bar inside of the panel-body content. I have included the  the fiddle and code.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m88p3d50/)

```css
html, body {
    background-color:#e9eaed;
}
.content {
    width:960px;
    height:0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.panel-group {
    width:430px;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
}
.panel-heading {
    width: 430px;
}
.panel-title {
    height:18px
}
.panel-title a {
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 10px 430px;
    margin: -10px -430px;
}
.panel-body {
    height:830px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 188px 241px 0;
}
.panel-group img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
}
.panel-group p {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
}
.panel-group .panel img {
    margin-left:400px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                          Accordion 1
                        </a>
                      </h4>

                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p><h1>Title</h1><br>A paragraph of text about something pertinant to the site which people could read should the feel the need to read about it. They could skip it as well but this keeps the initial view a good deal less text heavy, see?<br>- Some Source</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this fiddle I want to insert the scrollbar inside the body-content. Please help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple horizontal/vertical scroll bar inside panel-body you can add two extra div inside panel-body like

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="t1">
         <div class="t2"> your content goes here.....</div>
  </div>
```

and alter some css like

```
.panel-body {
        height:830px; width: 600px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: 188px 241px 0;
    }
       .t1 {
            max-height: 390px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        .t2 {
            height: 320px;
            width: 720px;
        }
```

you'll get a simple window scroll further you can also use plugin like
[MalihuFancyscroll](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html) for fancy looking scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m88p3d50/3/) / [FullScreen JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m88p3d50/3/embedded/result/) of your solution.

I used CSS rule `overflow:hidden` to add the proper scrollbar to the `<div id="collapseOne>` that wrapps the `<div class="panel-body">`.

I first checked for the HTML console to check which class was added to the `<div id="collapseOne">`. So I identifyied 2 class that was toggling for the *open* and *close* state of your accordion :

- `panel-collapse collapse` (state : closed)
- `panel-collapse collapse in` (state : opened)

I added to the `.collapse.in` class the rule `overflow : auto` which let the browser add x and y scrollbars if the content go out the initial width value.

I hope you understood the usage of this rule and this solution fits your need.

Comment: Thanku so much. But Scroll bar is dispalying top. See the fiddle.

Comment: Is this possible to display in bottom?